# How can I code this equation with double summation in R?

Tags: r

[image]

So I'm having hard time coding the above equation, mainly the part which contains that double sum over i's and over j.

I'n my case, my n = 200 and p = 15. My yi:s are in a vector Y = (y1,y2,...yn) that is vector of length 200 and Xij:s are in a matrix which has 15 columns and 200 rows. Bj:s are in a vector of length 15.

My own solution, which I'm fairly certain is wrong, is this:

`b0 <- 1/200 * sum(Y - sum(matr*b))`

And here is code which you can use to reproduce my vectors and matrix:

```
matr <- t(mvrnorm(15,mu= rep(0,200),diag(1,nrow = 200)))
Y <- rnorm(n = 200)
b <- rnorm(n = 15)
```

Comment: That is not reproducible without `set.seed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use matrix multiplication:

```
mean(y - x %*% b)
```

Note that if y and x are known and b is the least squares regression estimate of the coefficients then we can write it as:

```
fm <- lm(y ~ x + 0)
mean(resid(fm))
```

and that necessarily equals 0 if there is an intercept, i.e. a constant column in x, since the residual vector must be orthogonal to the range of x and taking the mean is the same as taking the inner product of the residuals and a vector whose elements are all the same (and equal to 1/n).